# Gradle DSL method not found: 'androidtestcompile()'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting an error like this when I am trying to import **build.gradle** file which I exported from Eclipse

**build.gradle code:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
```

app module build.gradle which has been generated by Eclipse looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':android-crop-master:lib:src:main')
        compile project(':sharebubbles_menu')
        compile project(':braintree-1.2.5-project')
        compile project(':facebook')       
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }
```

The following is screenshot.

[image]

Comment: which file you selected top level build.gradle file or module level build.gradle file ?

Comment: top level build.gradle file @Haresh

Comment: have you try with module level build.gradle file  ?

Comment: @Haresh top level build.gradle which has been generated by eclipse while exporting to gradle

Comment: In latest version of Android Studio have already provide option 'Import project  (Eclipse,ADT,Gradle etc.) ', So no need to create build.gradle from Eclipse manually, Newer version of Android Studio directly open Eclipse project and make it Android Studio gradle base automatically.

Comment: ok how to add dependencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75256/discussion-between-navakanth-and-haresh-chhelana).

Comment: For dependencies check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You should update the version of gradle/gradle-plugin/AS that you are using.

Use these versions:

```
 - AS 1.1.0
 - Gradle 2.2.1
 - Gradle plugin 1.1.0
```

Then change your build script:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

And your module script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    // The same
}

android {
        //Rename your instrumentTest folders to androidTest, e.g. git mv app/src/instrumentTest app/src/androidTest.
        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTestCompile.setRoot('tests')

    }
}
```

All info about the `Instrumentation Tests` migration is [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

I was following the instructions from the Android Developer's page for Instrumented Unit Tests.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

I was getting the same error. The errors went away when I moved my edits from the gradle.build (Project: xxx) file to the gradle.build (Module: App).

Thankfully I noticed that there are two gradle.build files or I would still be trying to compile now.